# Can't override my-account.phtml

Tags: magento2, customer

In my default.xml I have the following:

```
<move element="my-account-link" destination="header-wrapper" before="minicart" />
<referenceBlock name="header.panel.wrapper" remove="true" />
<referenceBlock name="top.links" remove="true" />
```

This moves the my account link next to the minicart, which is correct. But what I need to do now is customize the code that displays the "My Account" link. Replace the link with an icon for example.

I've attempted to override this by placing a file called `my-account.phtml` under `BRAND/THEME/Magento_Customer/templates/account/link/my-account.phtml` with the following code (replaces the `<li>` with a `<div>`):

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/**
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Link $block
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Escaper $escaper
 */
?>
<div class="link my-account-link">
    <a <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getLinkAttributes() ?>><?= $escaper->escapeHtml($block->getLabel()) ?></a>
</div>
```

But this isn't working. The original location of `my-account.phtml` is `magento-2.2.4.2/app/code/Magento/Customer/view/frontend/templates/account/link/my-account.phtml`.

I've cleared cache by running `bin/magento c:c`. Other changes work no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Upon further investigation it appears I need to add the following reference block:

```
<referenceBlock name="my-account-link">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Customer::account/link/my-account.phtml</argument>
     </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

Or, even shorter:

```
<referenceBlock name="my-account-link" template="Magento_Customer::account/link/my-account.phtml" />
```